# Page is not fitting all the content

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm creating a Sign-up webpage to practice CSS, but when I change the size of the window, it doesn't let me scroll over all the content, like you see in the images below.

Can you tell how I can fix it?
[image: page in full size][image: page not showing all content]

That's the code I've used in the body, container and form

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

body {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.932);
    color: #fff;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    width: 350px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: rgb(44, 44, 44);
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.100);
}

form {
    height: auto;
    font-size: 14px;
    display: grid;
    gap: 12px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Comment: perhaps post a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: hey, the problem is that when I change the window size I can't scroll through all the content, as you can see in the second image, the content doesn't start in the beginning of the form, it starts already in the middle